# Foreign character breaking when posted via multipart/form-data

Tags: django, google-app-engine, multipartform-data, django-nonrel

I am using django-nonrel on the google-app-engine.

When I'm posting a foreign character,

in my case Korean Character, with a multipart/form-data it is breaking.

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
```

For example, if I post a string '한글'

it is recorded in my database as a string '7ZWc6riA'.

From my research this is the common case in jsp,

and in Java it's solve as below:

```
String name = multipartRequest.getParameter("name");
name = new String(name.getBytes("8859_1"),"utf-8");
```

However, I was unable to find the equivalent in Django,

nor not quite sure if I can solve my problem with the same logic.

Any help/clue will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your page has a header and a meta tag which sets utf-8 content-type? By the way equivalent of your code is: `name.decode('utf-8')` if name is bytestring.

Comment: "Breaking" how? Show us the relevant code and the stacktrace!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an open issue for this problem.

Issue 2749: Blobstore handler breaking data encoding
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=2749

You can find several different options to go around this bug in the link above.

Personally, as a Django-nonrel user, I'd go with a solution shown below:

```
import logging
import quopri
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    class BlobRedirectFixMiddleware(object):
        def process_request(self, request):
            if request.method == 'POST' and 'HTTP_X_APPENGINE_BLOBUPLOAD' in request.META and request.META['HTTP_X_APPENGINE_BLOBUPLOAD'] == 'true':
                request.POST = request.POST.copy()
                log.info('POST before decoding: %s' % request.POST)
                for key in request.POST:
                    if key.startswith('_') or key == u'csrfmiddlewaretoken':
                        continue
                    value = request.POST[key]
                    if isinstance(value,(str, unicode)):
                        request.POST[key] = unicode(quopri.decodestring(value), 'iso_8859-2')
                log.info('POST after decoding: %s' % request.POST) 
            return None
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely with the HTML that you are serving rather than Django.  I'm using HTML5, I just need this meta tag in my  element.  I've tried various languages, and they all input fine.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
```

Comment: I didn't had the meta tag in my HTML, but adding it didn't solve my problem. I didn't have this problem when I was using mySQL on windows 2003 server, and on Django's development server running on my Mac OSX Lion.